# Why my disk is at full speed even though very little is written or read?

Tags: io

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda             429.60     9.00  170.20    2.00  2479.20    71.20    29.62    10.80   67.28   5.81 100.02
sdb               0.00   103.60  149.80   10.80   607.20   458.40    13.27   156.02 1151.45   6.23 100.00
sdc              46.00    17.40   42.60   11.60  1360.80   116.00    54.49     0.03    0.60   0.42   2.26
sdd               0.00     3.20  168.40    0.60   673.60    15.20     8.15     4.04   23.89   5.92 100.00
sde               0.00     0.00  162.60    0.00   656.80     0.00     8.08   168.36   19.75   6.15 100.00
sdf              52.20     0.00  181.80    0.00   893.60     0.00     9.83   167.00  195.67   5.50 100.00
```

disk speed is only 893 rkB/s. Only 181 read per second. Is that a lot?

Comment: 170.20 r/s is not a lot no. I do not understand your `rkB/s` but having 429.60 queued requests per second is not that much either. Kinda depends on what this machine is designed to do and what type of load it has at the measuring time.

Comment: so it's not a lot right?

Comment: Correct. So what was the question?

Comment: it's not a lot and yet disk utilization is 100%. why?

Comment: How have you verified it is at 100%, and what disk is it? SSD, hybrid, 3.5" mechanical, laptop mechanical?

Comment: What are the disk(s)?  SSDs?  SATA?  SAS? Some kind of RAID?  If they're single mechanical drives, what RPM?  A good 15K rpm SAS drive can do about 150-200 random IO operations/sec.  A SATA drive can do about 50-80 random IO operations/sec depending on RPM.  So 180 IO ops/sec would be right in line with what a SAS drive can do.